# when to use Set vs. Collection?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any practical difference between a `Set` and `Collection` in Java, besides the fact that a `Collection` can include the same element twice? They have the same methods.

(For example, does `Set` give me more options to use libraries which accept `Set`s but not `Collection`s?)

**edit:** I can think of at least 5 different situations to judge this question. Can anyone else come up with more? I want to make sure I understand the subtleties here.

1. designing a method which accepts an argument of `Set` or `Collection`. `Collection` is more general and accepts more possibilities of input. (if I'm designing a specific class or interface, I'm being nicer to my consumers and stricter on my subclassers/implementers if I use `Collection`.)
2. designing a method which returns a `Set` or `Collection`. `Set` offers more guarantees than `Collection` (even if it's just the guarantee not to include one element twice). (if I'm designing a specific class or interface, I'm being nicer to my consumers and stricter on my subclassers/implementers if I use `Set`.)
3. designing a class that implements the interface `Set` or `Collection`. Similar issues as #2. Users of my class/interface get more guarantees, subclassers/implementers have more responsibility.
4. designing an interface that extends the interface `Set` or `Collection`. Very similar to #3.
5. writing code that uses a `Set` or `Collection`. Here I might as well use `Set`; the only reasons for me to use `Collection` is if I get back a `Collection` from someone else's code, or if I have to handle a collection that contains duplicates.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is also the supertype of `List`, `Queue`, `Deque`, and others, so it gives you more options. For example, I try to use `Collection` as a parameter to library methods that shouldn't explicitly depend on a certain type of collection.

Generally, you should use the right tool for the job. If you don't want duplicates, use `Set` (or `SortedSet` if you want ordering, or `LinkedHashSet` if you want to maintain insertion order). If you want to allow duplicates, use `List`, and so on.

Comment: How does using a Collection give you *more* options? Using more general things usually give you *less* power.

Comment: It gives more options to the person calling a method that takes a Collection as parameter because they can pass a List, Set or Queue without having to do any conversion.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking from the point of view of the person writing a method accepting a Collection. For a method *returning* something, I prefer to use the appropriate type for the job, as I said.

Answer (score 8):

I think you already have it figured out-  use a `Set` when you want to specifically exclude duplicates.  `Collection` is generally the lowest common denominator, and it's useful to specify APIs that accept/return this, which leaves you room to change details later on if needed.  However if the details of your application require **unique entries**, use `Set` to enforce this.

Also worth considering is whether order is important to you; if it is, use `List`, or `LinkedHashSet` if you care about order *and* uniqueness.

Comment: API should usually return a more specific type then `Collection`. For example if it's possible to return a `List`, then do so. Only if you are not sure about the return type, you could consider returning `Collection`.

Answer (score 4):

As @mmyers states, Collection includes Set, as well as List.

When you declare something as a Set, rather than a Collection, you are saying that the variable cannot be a List or a Map.  It will always be a Collection, though.  So, any function that accepts a Collection will accept a Set, but a function that accepts a Set cannot take a Collection (unless you cast it to a Set).

Comment: Actually, Map does not extend Collection.

Comment: You are right, my mistake.  I just edited the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

See Java's [Collection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) for a good walk-through of Collection usage. In particular, check out the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing to consider...  Sets have extra overhead in time, memory, and coding in order to guarantee that there are no duplicates.  (Time and memory because sets are usually backed by a HashMap or a Tree, which adds overhead over a list or an array.  Coding because you have to implement the hashCode() and equals() methods.)

I usually use sets when I need a fast implementation of contains() and use Collection or List otherwise, even if the collection shouldn't have duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Set when that is what you want.

For example, a List without any order or duplicates. Methods like contains are quite useful.

A collection is much more generic. I believe that what mmyers wrote on their usage says it all.

Answer (score 1):

The practical difference is that Set enforces the **set** logic, i.e. no duplicates and unordered, while Collection does not. So if you need a Collection and you have no particular requirement for avoiding duplicates then use a Collection. If you have the requirement for Set then use Set. Generally use the highest interface possibble.

Comment: Highest in-terms of abstraction or highest-order level?

Answer (score 0):

As Collection is a super type of Set and SortedSet these can be passed to a method which expects a Collection.  Collection just means it may or may not be sorted, order or allow duplicates.