# What is the difference between Collection and Set interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, collections, interface, set, marker-interfaces

The declared method signatures seem to be equal. So what is the purpose of introducing Set interface rather then implementing Collection directly? Or is it just sort of a marker interface here?

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks, added "Java" to the post

Comment: What differences does the *Javadoc API* say there are? Look at both the types and the methods defined upon such, as well as the constraints: "The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included here for convenience. (The specifications accompanying these declarations have been tailored to the Set interface, but they do not contain any additional stipulations.)"

Comment: The tags here explain ^^

Comment: Its not always about the methods; having a Set interface, you can state in an API that you expect or return a Set and not an arbitrary Collection.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` guarantees that the collection will contain unique elements (no duplicates). A `Collection` does not guarantee this.

> The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection and adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited.
>
> Set also adds a stronger contract on the behavior of the **equals** and **hashCode** operations, allowing Set instances to be compared meaningfully even if their implementation types differ. Two Set instances are equal if they contain the same elements.

[The Set Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Note, `Set` does not preserve the order in which elements were inserted.
You `LinkedHashSet` if you need to preserve insertion order of the elements.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/821104/4587961

Answer (score 0):

I guess I kind of understood what you want to know exactly. :)

Source code shipped with JDK (src.zip) has 2 interfaces, `Collection` and `Set` and all the methods declared in `Collection` interface are re-declared in `Set` interface.
At first look it seems redundant to re-declare the methods. But if you look closely then you can find out that method signature is kept same as the `Collection` interface but comments are changed to describe what will be the behavior of methods in implementing classes.

**Why** `Set` interface exists if collection interface is sufficient enough in case of Set (as we are not introducing any new method in `Set` interface) (FYI: Here I'm ignoring  one method which is introduced in `Set` interface - `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);`).

**Ans**: Lets say you have two classes ClassA and ClassB implementing Collection interface and both of them are storing unique elements (just like Set). Now you have a method lets say `populateSet(Collection setImpl);` and you have code specific to deal with your ClassA & ClassB, and purpose of this method is you can use this method to pass ClassA and ClassB interchangeably, so far everything is okay. But now the problem with this method is you can pass the ArrayList to this method as Collection interface is generic one and your methos will start breaking. Which is why we needed one more interface to categorize all the set implementation under the single hood.